# Pass ClientCredentials.UserName to server

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, wcf-binding

**Web config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceCredentialsBehavior">
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="cool"    storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                </serviceCredentials>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceCredentialsBehavior" name="Service">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageAndUserName" name="SecuredByTransportEndpoint" contract="IService"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MessageAndUserName">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

**Client cfg:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" >
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:48097/WCFServer/Service.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
                  contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                  name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
            <identity>
                <dns value ="cool" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The scope is to pass ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName/Password through a secure connection.
I did x509 certificates with pluralsight self cert..

The error is:

> SOAP security negotiation with 'http://localhost:48097/WCFServer/Service.svc'
>   for target
>   'http://localhost:48097/WCFServer/Service.svc'
>   failed. See inner exception for more
>   details.

InnerException:

> The X.509 certificate CN=cool chain
>   building failed. The certificate that
>   was used has a trust chain that cannot
>   be verified. Replace the certificate
>   or change the
>   certificateValidationMode. A
>   certificate chain processed, but
>   terminated in a root certificate which
>   is not trusted by the trust provider.

How can i solve this exception?
Regards,
Sergiu.

Comment: **See inner exception for more details**

Comment: The X.509 certificate CN=cool chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using self signed certificate which is not trusted by default. You must tell your client application that it should trust the certificate:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="LocalCertValidation">
      <clientCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Reference this behavior from your endpoint configuration in client by `behaviorConfiguration="LocalCertValidation"`. To make it work you must install public certificate to current user's certification store under trusted people. You can also set validation mode to `None` and certificate will not be validated at all but that should be used only in development environment.

Comment: http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/4124/certid.png
I added it(i think), but exception says that i didn't.

Comment: At least one security token in the message could not be validated.
I put certificate in the Current User store, and now i receive error:
At least one security token in the message could not be validated.